# Export csv with laravel excel in specific folder

Tags: laravel, csv, laravel-excel

Hello I am trying to export a csv file in a specific folder, I have tried several things and have no results

By doing the following code it exports me normally in the default `/app/` folder

```
  public function export(){
    $super = Super::select('ano_plantacion','zona','sitio', 'manejo','sup_ha','codigo','rpend')->get();
    Excel::store(new SuperExport($super), 'Super.csv')); 
  }
```

Im try with this:

```
Excel::store(new SuperExport($super), 'Super.csv', storage_path('/app/export'));
```

Error:

```
"Trying to access array offset on value of type null"
```

And this:

```
Excel::store(new SuperExport($super), storage_path('/app/export/Super.csv'));
```

Error:

```
Impossible to create the root directory "C:\Users\pachi\Documents\Version_web\mpe_web\storage\app\C:/Users/pachi/Documents/Version_web/mpe_web/storage/app/export
```

Help pls

Comment: What about `Excel::store( new SuperExport($super), '/app/export/Super.csv' );`?

Comment: yeah it worked! but I create a new app/ folder inside app/ 
with this line it worked as I wanted:

`Excel::store( new SuperExport($super), '/export/Super.csv' );`

thanks, the solution was super simple, but I don't know why I didn't try that shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Excel `store()` method uses the default disk if you don't specify another one, which by default in laravel points to [`storage_path('app')`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5639581ea56ecd556cdf6e6edc37ce5795740fd7/config/filesystems.php#L48), you can just prepend the `export/` directory to the file name:

```
Excel::store( new SuperExport($super), '/export/Super.csv' );
```

---

Alternatively you can create a disk for the exports by adding the following array under the `'disks'` index in the `/config/filesystems.php` file:

```
'disks' => [
    // your other disks here, leave them as they are, and add this one

    'export' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/export'),
    ],

],
```

And then you specify that disk as the third parameter to the `store()` method:

```
Excel::store( new SuperExport($super), 'Super.csv', 'export' );
```